# failure on serverless deploy Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

all

As it said in the title, I just delete all the cloudformation stack and try to do the fresh deploy again. but when I run the `sls deploy --verbose`, it shows the error

> The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error:
>   Unresolved resource dependencies [ServerlessDeploymentBucket] in the
>   Resources block of the template
>
> For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*"
>   environment variable.

I double check my serverless.yml file, but found I don’t define a bucket with Name ServerlessDeploymentBucket.

Then I go to the AWS console, after clicking my root stack (I am using the serverless-split-stack plugin),
there is only a simple template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: The AWS CloudFormation template for this Serverless application
Resources:
  ServerlessDeploymentBucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
Outputs:
  ServerlessDeploymentBucketName:
    Value: !Ref ServerlessDeploymentBucket
```

while actually in my origin serverless.yaml, there are more than 1200 lines. Quite wondering what is the error related to the serverless. Appreciated for anyone could help. Thanks.

Edit: there are a bunch of plugin I am using which maybe useful for troubleshooting the error:

```
   serverless-content-encoding 
   serverless-pseudo-parameters      
   serverless-webpack 
   serverless-offline 
   serverless-plugin-split-stacks 
   serverless-plugin-custom-roles 
   serverless-domain-manager      
   serverless-s3-deploy serverless-plugin-tracing
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

is there any chance you are using template exported from an old stack?

By the way What happens if you just

- delete the stack
- and just sls deploy?

It will create the template for you (and the stack) and deploy it.